# How tensorflow handle the computional graph when executing sess.run?

Tags: tensorflow

when we using the code bellow:

```
output = NeuralNetwork(x,W)
loss = Loss(output, true_label)
train_op = Optimizer.minimize(loss)
sess.run([loss, train_op], feed_dict=feed)
```

does the tensorflow compute `output` twice, one for computing loss, one for computing the gradient, or compute `ouput` just once, using the computed `output` to compute `loss` and `gradient`?
Thanks!

edit.
when tensorflow run the following code:

```
output = NeuralNetwork(x,W)
ouput_plus_one = output+1
loss = Loss(output, true_label)
train_op = Optimizer.minimize(loss)
sess.run([output_plus_one, train_op], feed_dict=feed)
```

In this case, does tensorflow detect the overlapped subgraph between the subgraph of the `output_plus_one` and `train_op` and then compute `output` first?

Answer (score 1):

The `output` would only be computed once and then kept in memory until the the backward pass consumes it.

There is some optimization that can be made in TensorFlow that if a tensor is fast to compute but large and would sit in memory for a long time, we could probably discard the output and recompute it when we need it next time.

Comment: At the second question above, Does tensorflow detect the overlapped subgraph between the subgraph of the `output_plus_one` and `train_op` and then compute `output` first? Thanks

Comment: The `output` just one node on the graph. Its output tensors would be consumed by two nodes. That is it. The python layer of tensorflow would make sure there is only one node created for computing your output.